# Java OS Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, operating-system

I want to authenticate user with OS. I am getting username, password as input from user & I simply want to check with os whether that username, password is right or wrong.

I don't want to do LDAP authenticating. Only os authentication where my program is running. Second thing program should run on windows from xp on-wards, linux & if possible unix flavors.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

While googling I found : https://github.com/twall/jna

But still trying to figure out whether this library is right for my requirement or not

Comment: I suspect you need to use JNA. The only alternative I know is to read the shadow file (requiring you to access to it)

Comment: for linux its alternative way. Its unaccepted for my mgr to read from file. And for windows how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WAFFLE windows Authentication framework](http://waffle.codeplex.com/)

Steps for Windows Authentication using WAFFLE framework

**Step1**. Download following jars
   a.jna.jar
   b.waffle-jna.jar

**Step 2** :Place these jars in your class folders

**Step 3:** Using waffle in your Java code below is the code snippet

```
public boolean isValidUser(String username , String password){
  WindowsAuthProviderImpl authenticationProvider = new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
  IWindowsIdentity loggedOnUser = authenticationProvider.logonUser(username, password);
  if(!loggedOnUser.isGuest()){
        return true;
  }
   return false;
 }
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: do u have any idea about how to do authentication with os, if os is linux

Comment: one more thing, it not working on 64bit windows 7. I put wrong username, password combination still It list all group names & doesn't throw any error/exception

Answer (score 0):

Use GSS-API with Kerberos if your are in an Active Directory environment.

Comment: not looking for AD authentication anyway thanks for suggestion. Will keep in mind if doing auth with ad